# Get an Object from an Array using Json and Java

Tags: activiti

i have a table in the form of json that contains objects one of the variable of this object is u object how can i get this i explain it all with an example, i want to get **variable** using java how can i do it

```
  {
 "data": [
  {
  "id": "40406",
  "processInstanceId": "40398",
   "processInstanceUrl": "http://10.6.99.57:8888/activiti- 
   rest/service/history/historic-process-instances/40398",
   "taskId": null,
   "variable": {
   "name": "nbj",
    "type": "string",
    "value": "3",
    "scope": null
     }
       },
    {
      "id": "40408",
     "processInstanceId": "40398",
        "processInstanceUrl": "http://10.6.99.57:8888/activiti- 
     rest/service/history/historic-process-instances/40398",
      "taskId": null,
      "variable": {
      "name": "nom",
      "type": "string",
      "value": "yasmine",
       "scope": null
        }
         },
         {
       "id": "40404",
        "processInstanceId": "40398",
         "processInstanceUrl": "http://10.6.99.57:8888/activiti- 
          rest/service/history/historic-process-instances/40398",
          "taskId": null,
           "variable": {
           "name": "reponse",
            "type": "string",
             "value": "1",
             "scope": null
               }
                }
                ],
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sir please give me link to read approve or reject sugested edits.

Comment: no sir it can be done by 1 reputation users.

Comment: but i didn't find where it is ??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to execute the rest call and read the rest response using java. You can execute the call using the Spring RestTemplate class with 'restTemplate.exchange'. Then you'll want to read the response with the jackson library that will convert the json to java objects - in this case a collection of java objects. Baeldung have guides on [restTemplate](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list) and [jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson). You could base your java class on the java that [was originally used to generate the json](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/6.x/modules/activiti-rest/src/main/java/org/activiti/rest/service/api/history/HistoricProcessInstanceResponse.java). You'll probably find it useful to set @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) so that you don't have to model all of the json in your java. Or you could start by reading the response as String so that you can first see that the rest call is going through correctly.